# How to fetch the posts only in primary taxonomy with wp_query?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am developing a Wordpress website that has custom post types and custom taxonomies. It is able to choose multiple taxonomies and make it primary or secondary with yoastSEO for a post.

In the index page, there are many sections divided by taxonomies. Loading its own posts in its section. Duplicate posts were loaded in the page is not preferred therefore I would like to fetch the posts was selected in primary taxonomy only.

Is there are any relevant properties can be added in the args of `wp_query()`?

Comment: Did You read about param `tax_query`, `post__not_in`, and hook `wp_list_pluck` ?

Comment: I found the solution, it is meta_value, yoast SEO create _yoast_wpseo_primary_{category} for the posts. What I need is add this key into the args. Thank you guys

Comment: but this is not solution for duplicates with showed posts, if You have separate blocks(queries), pay attention for it.